# Finding Mersenne primes with Lucas–Lehmer primality test

Tags: scala, math, primes

I want to implement a `Stream` in Scala for finding Mersenne primes with the Lucas-Lehmer primality test. I already have:

```
object Main {
  //Mersenne Numbers:
  def msrn():Stream[BigInt] = 7#::msrn.map(_*2+1)
  def s():Stream[BigInt] = 14 #:: s.map(n => n*n-2)
  lazy val zips = s.zip(msrn)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     zips take 7 foreach println
  }
}
```

What I need to do now is find all Mersenne Numbers (elements in `msrn`) which divides the element in `s` and write them in a `Stream`.

Edit: Solved it:

```
object Main {
  def msrn():Stream[BigInt] = 7#::msrn.map(_*2+1)
  def s():Stream[BigInt] = 14 #:: s.map(n => n*n-2)
  lazy val zips = s.zip(msrn).filter(x=>x._1%x._2==0)
  def mersennePrimeStream():Stream[BigInt] = zips.map(x => x._2)
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     mersennePrimeStream take 4 foreach println
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make it shorter though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are much faster if you calculate the s-sequence modulo the Mersenne number you are testing:

```
object Main {
  def s(k: Int, m: BigInt) = Iterator.iterate(BigInt(14))(n => (n * n - 2) % m) drop k next
  lazy val msrn: Stream[(Int,BigInt)] = (0,BigInt(7)) #:: msrn.map(t => (t._1 + 1, t._2 * 2 + 1))
  val mersennePrimeStream = msrn filter(x => s(x._1, x._2) % x._2 == 0) map (_._2)
  def main(args: Array[String]) = mersennePrimeStream take 10 foreach println
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Amazing answer.